# How do i remove commas from an excel file using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm converting a file that automatically drops in a folder as a .txt into a csv file. Now there are some names on this file that includes a comma at the end. I want to know if theres a way to remove this comma.

**Here is the current script:**

```
Option Explicit

On Error Resume Next
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
XlApp.SetWarnings False
Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlSheet

Const xlCSV = 6

On Error Resume Next
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
XlApp.SetWarnings False

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileLocation:\& "filename.txt", , , 6, , , , , "|")

Set xlSheet = xlBook.worksheets.item(1)



XlApp.SetWarnings False

On Error Resume Next

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

xlSheet.Range("B:B").Delete

xlSheet.Range("C:C").Delete

xlSheet.Range("F:H").Delete

xlSheet.Range("G:K").Delete

xlSheet.Range("P:Q").Delete

xlSheet.Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert

xlSheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "name1"

xlSheet.Cells(1,2).Value = "name2"

xlSheet.Cells(1,3).Value = "name3"

xlSheet.Cells(1,4).Value = "name4"

xlSheet.Cells(1,5).Value = "here is where the comma appears for some files"

xlSheet.Cells(1,6).Value = "name5"

xlSheet.Cells(1,7).Value = "name6"

xlSheet.Cells(1,8).Value = "name7"

xlSheet.Cells(1,9).Value = "name8"

xlSheet.Cells(1,10).Value = "name9"

xlSheet.Cells(1,11).Value = "name10"

xlSheet.Cells(1,12).Value = "name11"

xlSheet.Cells(1,13).Value = "name0"

xlSheet.Cells(1,14).Value = "name22"

xlSheet.Cells(1,15).Value = "name24"




xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

xlBook.Saveas "Filelocation:\filename.csv", xlCSV

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

xlApp.Quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the replace function.

```
xlSheet.Cells(1,5).Value = replace(xlSheet.Cells(1,5).Value, ",", "")
```

to apply this you need to assign the new value to the cell.
Something like this will go through all the used cells in column E

```
For Each c In Cells.Range("E1:E" & Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
c.Value = Replace(c.Value, ",", "")
Next c
```

Comment: Just to clarify "xlsheet.cells(1,5)" correspond to column E:E in this columns some records have a comma and that's what I need to delete. if i apply the function would be something like  replace(xlSheet.Range("E:E").Value=",", "") but it fails to run the script

Comment: Do you only want to do it for cell E1? (Cells(1,5)) Then that is fine, else you will need to write some code to iterate through the column or row or area you want to remove the commas from.